# Wp_remote_post : send form data to an externtal CRM

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a form on my WordPress site that I need to send its data to a CRM using API.

**I don't have much knowledge with PHP**.

I am using JetFormBuilder and I am calling a hook the moment it is sent.

The problem is, I don't know how to get the dynamic form fields data.

I only need some field from the form and not all of them.

If I am inserting some dummy data it is sent, but I don't know how to change it to get the data by the field ID.

I would love to get some help.

This is my code (without the actual API URL and app id):

```
add_action( 'jet-form-builder/custom-action/send-to-crm', function( $request, $action_handler ) {

    $fields = array(
        'table' => 'Warranty',
        'phone' => '123456',
        'email' => 'email@email.com'    
        );

    wp_remote_post( 'https://myexternalurl.com', array(
            'method'      => 'POST',
                'timeout'     => 85,
                'httpversion' => '1.0',
                'blocking'    => false,
        
                    'headers'     => [
                    'accept' => 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    'X-Parse-Application-Id' => 'my-app-Id',
                    ],
                'body'        => json_encode( $fields )
                )
            );
    
}, 10, 2 );
```

I have tried to change it to:

```
$fields = array(
    'table' => 'Warranty',
    'phone' => $phone,
    'email' => $email   
    );
```

and to:

```
$fields = array(
    'table' => 'Warranty',
    'phone' => ['phone'],
    'email' => ['email']    
    );
```

but none of it worked.